# Why 20 is omitted from the file descriptor

Tags: c, file-descriptor

**EDIT**:

`lsof` shows that it's opened by `ptmx`. Thanks to @zwol

---

My code below prints the file descriptor returned from open. I noticed that 20 is missing. There is no similar question to the best of my knowledge.

*background:*

- Filesystem: ext4
- Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2

*code:*

```
int main()
{
    char name[2] = "a";
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        int fd = open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
        printf("fd is %d\n", fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*output:*

```
$ ./a.out 
fd is 3
fd is 4
fd is 5
...
fd is 18
fd is 19
fd is 21 <-- here
fd is 22
...
```

*lsof*

```
...
a.out   1815 ryan   19u   REG   8,16        0 42321 /tmp/tmp/a
a.out   1815 ryan   20u   CHR    5,2      0t0 15832 /dev/ptmx
a.out   1815 ryan   21u   REG   8,16        0 42321 /tmp/tmp/a
...
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What's the reason behind it? (What triggers `ptmx`)
2. Will there be more indices missing if I keep opening files? (More programs like `ptmx`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX says that every system call that allocates file descriptors must use the lowest number(s) that are not already in use. Therefore, descriptor number 20 must have already been open. Your sample program doesn't open anything before the loop, so it must have been inherited from your shell, or opened by the C library prior to main.

You can find out more by having your program print its PID and then sleep for a long time, after the loop, and then running `lsof` on it while it's sleeping.

Comment: It turns out to be a character special file opened by /dev/ptmx, do you have any reference from which I can find out the reason for triggering it?

Comment: /dev/ptmx is the outside interface of your terminal window's [pseudo-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty). It wouldn't normally be accessible to programs running inside the terminal (such as your shell and this program). I would suggest you contact the authors of whatever terminal-window software you're using and ask for an explanation.